# Jenkins issue with Trigger one build per property file

Tags: jenkins

Job A uses "For every property file, invoke one build" parameter factory to call downstream job B.
Here is the file pattern I am using:
d:\temp*.properties
There are two files in that folder:
build0.properties
build1.properties

each file looks something like this:

```
modified=SampleApp
```

Job B fails because job A is not setting the parameters from above file. If I look at the parameters for a build of Job B, they are empty.

The process works when I use "Parameters from properties file" parameter type instead of a parameter factory, and specify the full path to one of the files, so I know the files are in the right format. I do not want to add a parameter for each file I have,
since I will have these files generated dynamically.I would prefer to use the parameter factory if possible.

Comment: Just for the record, you are not using [jenkins-pipeline](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/) but freestyle jobs. As for your problem, I think the parameterized plugin allows you specify multiple files with their relative or absolute path, but not a file pattern or a source folder. I guess you have to specify each and every file that you want to read properties from...

Comment: @Pom12 jobs are getting triggered ..No issues with that, issue is just with the passage of parameter from file..Plugin clearly says "File Pattern"

Answer (score 0):

Issue with the file permissions, when I pointed to workspace directory with the file pattern It started workign fine.